# Finding a basis for polynomial vector spaces?

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces

Find a basis of the following vector space.

The vector space over $\Bbb C$ of polynomials $p(z)$ of degree at most $4$ with coefficients in $\Bbb C$ satisfying $p(z) = p(−z)$ for all $z ∈ \Bbb C$ and $p(−2) = 0$.

How do you do this?

Comment: Start by writing down the general polynomial of degree four, then see what the hypotheses imply about the coefficients thereof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to impose that for a generic polynomial $\alpha x^4+\beta x^3+\gamma x^2+\delta x+\varepsilon \in\mathbb C_{\le 4}[x]$ the conditions:
$$P(-2)=0\implies16\alpha-8\beta+4\gamma-2\delta+\varepsilon=0 \text{ and }$$
$$\forall x\in\mathbb C:P(x)=P(-x)\iff2\beta x^3+2\delta x=0\iff\beta x^3+\delta x=0.$$
From the first condition we get $\varepsilon=2\delta-4\gamma+8\beta-16\alpha=-16\alpha-4\gamma$, since $\beta$ and $\delta$ are $0$. 
Then we have two free parameters $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ and a basis of this space is
$$\mathcal B=\{x^4-16,x^2-4\}$$

Answer (score 0):

Any fourth degree polynomial can be written $p(z)= az^4+ bz^3+ cz^2+ dz+ e$.  The requirement that $p(z)= p(-z)$ means that $az^4+ bz^3+ cz^2+ dz+ e= az^4- bz^3+ cz^2- dz+ e$ so that $bz^3+ dz= -bz^3- dz$ and then $bz^2+ dz= 0$ for all $z$ so that $b= d= 0$.  That is, since this is an "even" function only the even powers of $z$ have non-zero coefficient.  The condition that $p(-2)= 0$ then gives $16a+ 4c+ e= 0$.  We can write that as $e= -16a-  4c$.

The polynomial can be written as $az^4+ cz^2-16a- 4c= a(z^4- 16)+ c(z^2- 4)$